# IndexSearcher returns deleted documents after upgrade from 3.5 to 4.4

Tags: java, lucene

In my web application that supports searching with a paged display of the result, I've upgraded Lucene from release 3.5 to 4.4. Now `IndexSearcher.search` returns deleted documents when I search for documents:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, filter, pageStart + pageSize);

int totalCount = results.totalHits;
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int pageEnd = Math.min(results.totalHits, pageStart + pageSize);
List<Long> rowIdList = new ArrayList<Long>(Math.max(pageEnd - pageStart, 0));

for (int i = pageStart; i < pageEnd; i++) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
    rowIdList.add(Long.parseLong(doc.get("rowid")));
}
```

As a result I have duplicate row IDs in `rowIdList` causing problems later on. I've now added code to remove the duplicates from `rowIdList`. That works except for the display of the number of total matches, which is usually too high. In addition, the a page of search result often displays less matches than it should.

In Lucene 4.4, what is to correct way to create of list of hits without deleted documents so that the number of retrieved hits and the number of total hits is correct?

Comment: `IndexSearcher.search` should not return deleted documents.  My first guess would be that the documents in question have not actually been deleted.  Are you sure there are no problems with how you are deleting (or updating) documents?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It seems I've made a mistake in upgrading the code: the field that servers as a unique id is no longer indexed (only stored). It will take some time to rebuild the index. But I'm confident it'll fix it.

Comment: Indexing the unique id field has indeed solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed turned out that I hadn't correctly configured the field. The field that serves as the primary key both in Lucene and in my database needs to be both *indexed* (so Lucene finds the documents to update or delete) and *stored* (so I have the primary key of each document and can use it for a lookup in the database).

Comment: How was the field setup exactly in the end ? There are multiple `IndexOptions` types and I wonder if the type matters. For example, TextField() will implicitly set index options to `IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS`, while using Field() will depend on its 3rd argument; could be e.g. `FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED)` that has index options set to `IndexOptions.DOCS`.